# PhpWord roman numeral for page number

Tags: php, phpword

I'm using this phpword library: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

And I have a trouble about roman numeral in page number, Is it possible for phpword to show page number in roman numeral instead of standard numeral?

i found this line of code in the library:

```
protected $fieldsArray = array(
        'PAGE' => array(
           'properties' => array(
               'format' => array('Arabic', 'ArabicDash', 'alphabetic', 'ALPHABETIC', 'roman', 'ROMAN'),
           ),
           'options' => array('PreserveFormat'),
        ),
...
);
```

just wonder how i can get it.

Comment: My guess, from a quick search in the code base, would be that you simply have to set the footnote properties, as in this example here on line 53ff. - https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/4fa945561f02893263e311e4c7c745df3a5dfee0/samples/Sample_06_Footnote.php#L53

Comment: As far as i try, it's only work for footnote, but not for page number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this as follows

```
$phpWord = new PhpWord();
$section = $phpWord->addSection();
$footer = $section->addFooter();
$textRun = $footer->addTextRun(array('alignment' => Jc::CENTER));
$textRun->addField('PAGE', array('format' => 'ROMAN'));
$textRun->addText(' of ');
$textRun->addField('NUMPAGES', array('format' => 'ROMAN'));
```

Comment: it's for footnote not for page number.